# Haskell take ascending (+1) part of list

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to take init part of list while elements differs from previous only by one. A simple task could be implemented like:

```
takeAsc:: (Eq a, Enum a) => [a] -> [a]
takeAsc [] = []
takeAsc [x] = [x]
takeAsc (x:y:xs)
  |y == succ x = x: takeAsc(y:xs)
  |otherwise   = [x]
```

But that's just hurt my feelings. I believe, that's pretty wide used pattern, and I'm just missing some specific function. I've tried to use groupBy or takeWhile, but it looks like they do not do what I want.
Could anybody point more elegant solution for that?

Comment: I think this definition is pretty good and quite normal, except that you missed the one-element-list case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement it as

```
takeAsc [] = []
takeAsc xss@(x:xs) = (x:) $ map fst $ takeWhile (uncurry (==)) $ zip xs $ map succ xss
```

You still have to include both cases, though.

```
> takeAsc [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
> takeAsc [1, 3, 4, 5]
[1]
```

If you don't like that it always returns at least 1 element for a non-empty list, you would have to use a more verbose solution like you have above, but if you're going for a one-liner this is the best I can come up with.

Comment: Thank you, I've also thought about toupling for a one liner, but wasn't smart enough for a final implementation.

Comment: Don't say "not smart enough", these patterns just take a while to figure out. The more you see solutions like this the more you'll be able to use them. When I started learning haskell I was in the same position, but a few years later these patterns become like second nature, just like when I started learning Python, it took some time to learn the patterns.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be

```
takeAsc :: (Enum a, Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
takeAsc []     = []
takeAsc (x:xs) = (x:) . map fst . takeWhile pred . zip xs $ x:xs
  where pred (a, b) = a == succ b
```

Or in English,

1. On an empty list, empty list
2. Pair each element of the list with previous element in the list, elide the first element
3. Take pairs while the `succ` of `b` is `a`
4. Remove the second element of the pair
5. Stick the first element back on

It avoids somewhat icky explicit recursion and GHC should be clever enough to optimize this pretty well.

Comment: This drops the last element though: `takeAsc [1, 2, 3, 4] == [1, 2, 3]`.  I came up with a similar implementation of `map fst $ takeWhile (uncurry (==)) $ zip xs $ map pred $ tail xs` which does the same thing...

Comment: @bheklilr Fixed with some pattern matching

Comment: I would also recommend renaming your local `pred` function, since it overrides the `pred` function defined for `Enum`, it could easily lead to confusion.  We also have essentially the same solution at this point.